# Basic probability ('at least one')

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the probability of at least one green question being asked in a series of 4 questions. Order has no influence. There are 23 red questions and 14 green questions (total of 37). There are always 4 questions in a row, ***but***, once any question is asked once, it will not return again (this is where I get stuck).

How should I approach this and how do I take into account that a question is never asked twice?

My current reasoning is this:

- The only option that does not have at least one green question, is the option where **all** questions are red
- Therefore the chance that at least one question is green, is 1 - the chance that all questions are red
- Every question can only be used once
- So the chance that every question is red is (23 / 37) * (22 / 36) * (21 / 35) * (20 / 34) = 0,13
- So the chance of at least on question being green is 1 - 0,13 = 0,87 (?)

Sorry for not being able to write this down scientifically, I've never been educated in that.

Comment: Please show how you attempted to solve the problem. Also here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Comment: With mutually exclusive what?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right.

The probability of a red question coming up next is always

$$ \frac{number\, of \,possible \,red \,questions}{number\, of\, total \,questions} $$

After each time a red question is asked you have to update the number of red questions and the number of total questions.

By multiplying each of the partial probabilities of getting asked a red question next you get the probability of getting asked only red questions.

The probability that out of 4 questions at least one is green is equal to 1 - the probability that none are green which is equal to 1 - the probability that all are red.